# Contradiction in simple complex integral: should this pole contribute?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, physics, mathematical-physics, complex-integration

This is a follow-up question to [a post I made on Physics SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/689539/feynman-diagrams-cant-wick-rotate-due-to-poles-in-first-and-third-p-0-quadra). TLDR; Essentially I have derived an apparent contradiction, starting from a simple integral. It feels like I'm missing something quite elementary and trivial, but I cannot seem to resolve it.

---

Consider the following integral, whose approximate form is commonly finds [in physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-loop_Feynman_diagram).

$$f(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{dz}{\left(-z^2 + m^2 - i\epsilon\right )^2 \left(-(z-x)^2+ M^2 -i \epsilon\right)} \tag{1}$$

$m,M>0$ are positive real numbers, $x$ is a positive real number (which we may allow to be complex), and $\epsilon>0$ is an infinitesimal small number which shifts the poles away from the real axis. In the complex $z$ plane, the integral looks as follows:

[image]

The blue dots correspond to the double-poles at $z=\pm (m - i\epsilon)$, and red dots correspond to the single-poles at $z=x\pm (M-i\epsilon )$. The green line represents the integration contour. **Notice that the pole at $z=x-M+i\epsilon$ resides in the $1^{\textrm{st}}$ quadrant.**

Now let's apply the technique of [Feynman parameterization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_parametrization), which combines both the rational terms in the integrand into a single rational function.

$$\begin{align}
f(x)&=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}dz \int_0^1 du_1 \int_0^{1-u_1} du_2 \frac{2!}{\left[ 
 (1-u_1-u_2)\left( -(z-x)^2+ M^2 -i \epsilon \right)+u_2 \left( -z^2 + m^2 - i\epsilon\right) +u_3 \left( -z^2 + m^2 - i\epsilon \right) \right]^3} \\
&= \int_0^1 du_1 \int_0^{1-u_1} du_2 \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}dz \frac{2}{\left[-(z-(1-u_1-u_2)x)^2-(u_1+u_2)(1-u_1-u_2)x^2+(1-u_1-u_2)M^2+(u_1+u_2)m^2-i\epsilon\right]^3} \\
&= \int_0^1 du_1 \int_0^{1-u_1} du_2 \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}dz \frac{2}{\left[-z^2+g(u_1,u_2,x)^2-i\epsilon\right]^3} \tag{2}
\end{align}$$

In the final expression above, note that no matter if $g^2$ is positive or negative, the triple-poles will always lie in the $2^{\textrm{nd}}$ and $4^{\textrm{th}}$ quadrants.

[image]

Since no poles $1^{\textrm{st}}$ and $3^{\textrm{rd}}$ quadrants, we may rotate the contour counter-clockwise by $90^\circ$, also known as [Wick-Rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wick_rotation). We now have the following expression:

$$f(x)=\int_0^1 du_1 \int_0^{1-u_1} du_2 \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} i dz \, \frac{1}{\left[z^2+g(u_1,u_2,x)^2 -i\epsilon\right]^3} \tag{3}$$

Let's now reverse all the previous algebraic steps, but using the Wick-rotated expression. This will finally give us (compare with (1)):

$$f(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{d(iz)}{\left(z^2 + m^2 -i\epsilon\right )^2 \left(-(iz-x)^2+ M^2 -i\epsilon\right)} \tag{4}$$

**But this is none other than the Wick-rotated version of the original integral! This is explicitly telling us that:**

$$\int_{\Gamma_1} I(z) dz= \int_{\Gamma_2} I(z) dz \tag{5}$$

where $\Gamma_1$ is the contour along the real axis, $\Gamma_2$ is the contour along the imaginary axis, and $I(z)$ is the integrand in (1). Note that this is expression was derived by @QMechanic in the [PSE post mentioned previously](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/689539/feynman-diagrams-cant-wick-rotate-due-to-poles-in-first-and-third-p-0-quadra). The essence of this derivation is found in most introductory textbooks on Quantum Field Theory.

On the other hand, if we tried to smoothly rotate the original contour by $90^\circ$, we would unavoidably pick up the residue of the pole in the $1^{\textrm{st}}$ contour.

$$\int_{\Gamma_1} I(z) dz= 2\pi i \,\textrm{Res} \left(I(z);z=x-M-i\epsilon \right)+ \int_{\Gamma_2} I(z) dz \tag{6}$$

Below you can see an illustration of this intuitive equation.

[image]

Combining (5) and (6), we see that the residue must be zero. **But we can calculate this residue and show it isn't zero, a contradiction!**

$$\textrm{Res} \left(I(z);z=x-M-i\epsilon \right)=\frac{1}{2M\left(-(x-M)^2+m^2\right)}\overset{?}{\neq} 0 \tag{7}$$

**So what's going on here? How can I resolve this contradiction?**

---

### Edit 1: A possible resolution.

I've just realized an issue in the algebraic steps. In (2), as per @Maxim's comment, I shifted $z\rightarrow z+(1-u_1-u_2)x$ in order to remove the term linear in $z$. This was fine, since $x$ was real-valued.

However when reversing these steps later, going from (3) to (4), the equivalent shift would be $z\rightarrow z+i(1-u_2-u_2)x$. This is not valid since for arbitrary $x$ the shift may hop over one of the poles! The resulting shifted-contour would not be homotopic to the original one! For it to be valid we would need $x$ to be imaginary.

If we have analytic continuation in mind, we could simply assume at this step that $x$ is actually purely imaginary. But then our original shift $z\rightarrow z+(1-u_1-u_2)x$ would not be valid for the same reason!

Comment: If $m, M, x, \epsilon$ are positive, then
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty I(z) \, dz - \int_{-i \infty}^{i \infty} I(z) \, dz =
2 \pi i \, [x > M]
 \operatorname* {Res}_{z = x - \sqrt {M^2 - i \epsilon}} I(z)$$
for all sufficiently small $\epsilon$, where $\sqrt z$ is the principal value of the square root, it's just an application of the residue theorem. What is $g(u_1, u_2, x)$? In the previous line, there is a term which is linear in $z$ inside the square brackets.

Comment: @Maxim That equation is exactly what I wrote at the end of my question, the punchline of this paradox. The term linear in $z$ is removed by shifting the integration variable via $z\rightarrow z+(1-u_1-u_2)x$. The remaining real valued part I simply call $g$.

Comment: @Maxim Your comment made me realize a possible resolution. See my edit.

Comment: I was going to say that the integrand in (3) should be $2 i/(z^2 + g^2 - i \epsilon)^3$, the sign of $\epsilon$ matters.

Comment: @Maxim Oh yeah you’re right. I was assuming $g^2>0$ so that the poles were along the real axis (left picture) and thus the $\epsilon$ could be sensibly taken to 0. But this isn’t necessarily true, so I should keep the $-i\epsilon$ term.

Comment: Sorry gents, I have a fundamental problem. Are we sure the poles of the integrand of (1) are $z=\pm (m-i\varepsilon)$ and $z=x\pm(M-i\varepsilon)$ ? We want $z^2=m^2-i\varepsilon$ so I would expect these two poles to be $z=\pm\sqrt{|u|}e^{i\varphi/2}$ where $|u|=\sqrt{m^4+\varepsilon^2}$ and $\varphi=\arctan(-\varepsilon/m^2)\,.$ (This is from $m^2-i\varepsilon=ue^{i\varphi}$.)

Comment: @KurtG. Your calcultion is correct, except it should be $\varphi =\arctan(-\varepsilon / m^2)$. We expand to leading order in $\varepsilon$ and relabel any infinitesimal parameter (such as $C\varepsilon^2$ where C is a constant) as $\varepsilon$ since all that matters is the fact that it’s infinitesimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to this. The integrals along the real and imaginary $z$ axes are of course not equal, the difference being given by the finite pole contribution as mentioned in (6) and (7) of my OP. The logic given in my edit, about why it is not possible to reverse the Feynman parameterization (i.e. going from (3) to (4)), is correct.

The broader issue motivating this post is that in physics, we would naively expect (1) and (4) to be the same. One arrives at integrals similar to (1) when calculating Feynman diagrams in Minkowski signature, whereas one would naively expect the same calculation in Euclidean signature to give rise to the "Wick-rotated" form of the same integral (e.g. (4) compared to (1)). For most 'normal' quantum field theories we expect the Minkowski and Euclidean predictions to coincide. Therefore the fact that these two integrals don't agree seems to be a big issue. However this issue can be resolved by going back to the drawing board, and seeing how these kinds of integrals really arise in the first  place.

All this is explained in [my PSE answer here.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/689539/feynman-diagrams-cant-wick-rotate-due-to-poles-in-first-and-third-p-0-quadra?noredirect=1#comment1563951_689539)

Answer (score 1):

A quick numerical experiment in python gives no reason to believe that the integrals (1) and (4) should give different results.

```
from scipy.integrate import quad, nquad
import cmath

def integrand( z, m, M, eps, x, which ):
    ie = complex(0,1)*eps
    tmp1 = (-z**2 + m**2 - ie)**2
    tmp2 = (-(z-x)**2 + M**2 - ie)
    if which == "re":
       return( (1/tmp1/tmp2).real )
    else:
       return( (1/tmp1/tmp2).imag )

def integrand_wick( z, m, M, eps, x, which ):
    ie = complex(0,1)*eps
    iz = complex(0,1)*z
    i = complex(0,1)
    tmp1 = (z**2 + m**2 - ie)**2
    tmp2 = (-(iz-x)**2 + M**2 - ie)
    if which == "re":
       return( (i/tmp1/tmp2).real )
    else:
       return( (i/tmp1/tmp2).imag )


 m = 1.0
 M = 1.0
 eps = 1.0
 x = 1.0

 print( quad( integrand, -20, 20, args = ( m, M, eps, x, "re" ) ) )
 print( quad( integrand, -20, 20, args = ( m, M, eps, x, "im" ) ) )
 print( quad( integrand_wick, -20, 20, args = ( m, M, eps, x, "re" ) ) )
 print( quad( integrand_wick, -20, 20, args = ( m, M, eps, x, "im" ) ) )
```

The output is

```
(-0.49033163694725157, 5.153607661012333e-09)
(-0.35979795020946703, 3.859702046164447e-09)
(-0.49033176263804457, 4.841029106680306e-11)
(-0.35979807319732326, 4.2856183711173664e-11)
```

The very small numbers are the accuracies achieved by quad.

Comment: Could you post the results of this code?

Comment: So the difference between the real and imaginary parts is $≈10^{-7}$. Although I see this is larger than the respective accuracies, they are still oddly close to zero, in which case (1) and (4) would be equal.

Comment: These outputs depend a lot on the integration bounds ( here $\pm 20$ ) and numeric integration is never perfect. Can you run that code yourself ? If (1) and (4) were different we should find parameters $m,M,\epsilon,x$ where the differences become huge. Also (my complex analysis knowledge is a bit rusty) : should (1) and (4) not obviously be equal ?

Comment: I’ll try to run it when I get to my computer. If one can start at (3), and reverse all the algebraic steps in (2), then one would arrive at (4) and thus (1) and (4) would be equal.

Comment: I solved the issue. These integrals are not equal, as is clear from the reasoning in my OP and the numerics of your answer. See [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/689539/feynman-diagrams-cant-wick-rotate-due-to-poles-in-first-and-third-p-0-quadra?noredirect=1#comment1563951_689539) for the full solution.

Comment: @ArturodonJuan . Many thanks. For me it is definitely time to catch up now. There must be a lot to learn from this example.